# Action on unlock/login

Tags: 13.10, login, lock-screen

I need to run custom command on every login and unlock screen (e.g. user didn't logged out but lock screen).

Do you have any ideas how I can implement it?

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a simple bash  script with following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
command='<your-command>' 
eval $command
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver',member='ActiveChanged'" | while read line ; do 
        if [ x"$(echo "$line" | grep 'boolean false')" != x ] ; then 
           eval $command    
        fi
done
```

Now Add it to **Startup applications -> Add**  and type : `bash  <path-to-script>` in Command box.

Comment: It doesn't works just for login

Comment: ok, I have edited it. It should work.

Comment: Can you explain `dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver',member='ActiveChanged'" | while read line ; do 
        if [ x"$(echo "$line" | grep 'boolean false')" != x ] ; then 
           eval $command    
        fi` part.

Comment: The dbus-monitor  is used to monitor messages passing through D-Bus message bus.In the above line dbus-monitor watch the message of gnome screen-saver whose output contain ` boolean true` when screen is locked and `boolean false` when screen is unlocked. Here output is equated with string `boolean false` to execute some command
`.

Comment: Why we need to execute eval before dbus-monitor command?

Comment: So that it can execute command when user login on startup.